# TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

Tags: python, tuples, typeerror, immutability, isinstance

If you're like me, you've probably tried:

```
isinstance(my_var, [list, tuple])
```

only to get:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

Now I fully understand the issue (the error message is clear) and how to fix it.
I also understand the difference between a list and a tuple (mutable vs unmutable).

However, what I'm trying to understand is what the tradeoffs are for the Python interpreter to also allow for a list to be provided as isinstance arg 2? (The code anyway already needs to check whether the argument is a scalar or a tuple)

If you're like me, it would have saved quite a few having to go back-n-forth iterations applying fixes, so I'm curious if perhaps there are performance or other reasons for Python standard functions to not mix the acceptance of lists and tuples here?

Comment: Analagous and relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/45118023/6260170

Comment: This reads more like a rant than a question. Furthermore, it's not something that's really answerable except by the python core team. All languages make questionable decisions.

Comment: @JaredSmith, sorry, not meant to be a rant. Just trying to learn what the pros/cons would be for Python to also accept a list in cases like these? I've clarified the motivation behind my question a bit.

Comment: It's a reasonable question, but read the answer I linked to above, there really isn't any reason to accept a list here. However, unlike the str.startswith case, it doesn't have the argument that you need a special case for a single string

Comment: The link is interesting read. Tnx. However, I would argue that assuming "all-things-being-equal" holds (which I'm not sure it does here?), user-friendliness is an important item also?

Comment: @HansBouwmeester it is. However there's more than one dimension to user friendliness. Another is not breaking existing code. If they change their minds at some point in the future to start allowing lists, all of the extant code that uses tuples will still work fine. *Nota Bene*: the reverse is *not* true: if they had allowed lists from the beginning and then decided oops, no, that was a bad idea then they'd be stuck with it or have to break working code.

Comment: Certainly valid tradeoffs. However, I'm still curious as to why Python accepts a "list-like" in many (most?) cases where here they decided it must be a tuple. Wouldn't this be against the duck-typing principle?

Comment: @HansBouwmeester possibly, but who knows? We generally don't allow questions that can only be answered by the language designers because they tend to (understandably) attract a lot of speculation.