# Pandas: search list of keywords in the text column and tag it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have bag of words as elements in a list format. I am trying to search if each and every single of these words appear in the pandas data frame ONLY if it 'startswith' the element in the list. I have tried 'startswith' and 'contains' to compare.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
# list of words to search for
searchwords = ['harry','harry potter','secret garden']

# Data
l1 = [1, 2, 3,4,5]
l2 = ['Harry Potter is a great book',
      'Harry Potter is very famous',
      'I enjoyed reading Harry Potter series',
      'LOTR is also a great book along',
      'Have you read Secret Garden as well?'
]
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':l1,'text':l2})
df['text'] = df['text'].str.lower()

# Preview df:
    id  text
0   1   harry potter is a great book
1   2   harry potter is very famous
2   3   i enjoyed reading harry potter series
3   4   lotr is also a great book along
4   5   have you read secret garden as well?
```

Try #1:

```
When I run this command it picks it up and gives me the results through out the text column. Not what I am looking for. I just used to check if I am doing things right for an example reasons for my understanding.
df[df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(searchwords))]
```

Try #2: 
    When I run this command it returns nothing. Why is that? I am doing something wrong? When I search 'harry' as single it works, but not when I pass in the list of elements.

```
df[df['text'].str.startswith('harry')] # works with single string.
df[df['text'].str.startswith('|'.join(searchwords))] # returns nothing!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `startswith` with a `tuple`

**Ex:**

```
searchwords = ['harry','harry potter','secret garden']

# Data
l1 = [1, 2, 3,4,5]
l2 = ['Harry Potter is a great book',
      'Harry Potter is very famous',
      'I enjoyed reading Harry Potter series',
      'LOTR is also a great book along',
      'Have you read Secret Garden as well?'
]
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':l1,'text':l2})
df['text'] = df['text'].str.lower()

print(df[df['text'].str.startswith(tuple(searchwords))] )
```

**Output:**

```
   id                          text
0   1  harry potter is a great book
1   2   harry potter is very famous
```

Comment: interesting +1, can you please explain how startswith is able to interpret tuple.. ?

Comment: This is interesting. This only works for startswith and endswith. Never would have guessed to use tuple!

Comment: thanks thats good, but why only tuple, i mean why not just take the list, is it because its written that way or tuple has some special property which i am unaware of or am i missing something here..@Rakesh

Comment: this pretty much clears it.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117924/how-does-str-startswith-really-work

Answer (score 2):

since `startswith` accepts str and no regex, use `str.findall`

```
df[df['text'].str.findall('^(?:'+'|'.join(searchwords) + ')').apply(len) > 0]
```

**Output**

```
   id                          text
0   1  harry potter is a great book
1   2   harry potter is very famous
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt solution `^(?:` does the 'startswith'? curious how to do endswith? didn't know that 'startwith' can't use regex

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a tuple in `startswith` function to check for multiple words 
See this [str.startswith with a list of strings to test for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461847/str-startswith-with-a-list-of-strings-to-test-for)

In your case, you can do

```
df['text'].str.startswith(tuple(searchwords))

Out:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: text, dtype: bool
```